# JavaScript/NodeJS: checking instanceof for parent method

Tags: javascript, node.js, instanceof

In Solid's NodeJS implementation, I can see the following:

```
module.exports = HTTPError

function HTTPError (status, message) {
  if (!(this instanceof HTTPError)) {
    return new HTTPError(status, message)
}
```

What's the point behind this? In which case would said method instance not pass `instanceof` check? I assume this isn't redundant, as I now think of it, but can't find logic behind it.

[Link to mentioned code on GitHub](https://github.com/solid/node-solid-server/blob/master/lib/http-error.js#L1-L6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference occurs depending on the presence of `new` keyword.
Consider the following example:

```js
function HTTPError(status, message) {
  if (!(this instanceof HTTPError)) {
    console.log("called without new. Status is " + status);
    return new HTTPError(status, message)
  } else {
    console.log("called with new. Status is " + status);
  }
  this.status = status;
}

const i = HTTPError(500);
const i2 = new HTTPError(400);
console.log(i);
console.log(i2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `this instanceof HTTPError` check is to allow the class to be called as regular function. `HTTPError` class mimics built-in JavaScript classes like `Error` that can be constructed with and without `new`:

```
Error() instanceof Error; // true
HTTPError() instanceof HTTPError; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

This allows for both calls to be possible, as a class instance:

```
let myError = new HTTPError('status', 'message');
```

and as a function call:

```
let myError = HTTPError('status', 'message');
```

In the function call case, `this` is undefined in the body of the function, thus, returning `new HTTPError` will create an instance of the class.